# int() function not working when accepting an input

Tags: python, integer

I need to write a python program to accept an integer and display its binary and octal equivalent. I have tried different formats, but keep getting errors on my int() function.

This is what I have

```py
dec = int(input())

print("The decimal value of", dec, "is:")
print(bin(dec), "in binary.")
print(oct(dec), "in octal.")
```

This is the error:

```
5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-154-9d3dcb9e828e> in <module>()
----> 1 dec = int(input())
      2 
      3 print("The decimal value of", dec, "is:")
      4 print(bin(dec), "in binary.")
      5 print(oct(dec), "in octal.")

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Is this your complete code? I think perhaps you have defined it before you use `input()`

Comment: Are you using Python 3+, or Python 2?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the value of `input` not referencing the built-in function by that name. Did you define a variable, `input`, prior to the code you provided? If you set something like `input = 'test'`, and then tried to run `dec = int(input())`, you will get the error you describe. Change the name of the variable, `input`, so that it isn't overwriting the built-in function, `input`, that you would like to call.

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem
You want to print the number but it gives you an error right? That's because you are trying to print an integer with a string. That is not possible. So you want to convert the integer to a string to print it.

Your final code should look like this

```
dec = int(input("Your input: "))

str(dec)

print("The decimal value of", dec, "is:")
bin(int(dec))
str(dec) # Turning to string for binary printing
print(bin(dec), "in binary.")
oct(int(dec))
str(dec) # Turning to string for octal printing
print(oct(dec), "in octal.")
```